# How to move spotfire 7.5 database from one SQL server to other

Tags: tibco, spotfire

I have a Spotfire 7.5 setup on my machine. I am using SQL server of another machine to keep the Spotfire database. Now I need to move my Spotfire database on another machine. I took the backup of my Spotfire database and restored on the SQL server of another machine.

Now I want to edit the bootstrap.xml to point my 'Spotfire' db which is now on new SQL server. But I am unable to do this as when I open the configuration tool by giving the password, it gets opened but the bootstrap tab(in which I need to edit the database server) shows disabled. And if I am directly editing the file' bootdtrap.xml' in notepad then it not works.

Can anyone help me, how to achieve this?

Also do I need to perform some other steps? Please share that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to move the database using the configuration tool. I have clicked on the New bootstrap file creation option and created a new one. It automatically took my last changes for other tabs i.e. Configuration tab, Administration tab etc. And my Spotfire database moved successfully and it is working.